# A Fairy Chess Ladder

Tags: wordplay, english, word-ladder

This is yet a **fairy**ly ordinary word ladder on the chessboard.

Sequence:

> PAWN  > KNIGHT > ROOK > QUEEN > KING

Rules:

> Each step you can do ONE of the following:
>
> 1) Add a letter
>
> 2) Remove a letter
>
> 3) Change a letter
>
> ### 4) Introducing the Fairy Chess - ANAGRAM:
>
> Shuffle the whole word into another legitimate word, e.g. SHOP > POSH

Note:

> 1) only words in Wiktionary with an “English” entry are allowed. No “Old English”, “Middle English”,…
>
> 2) For fun and simplicity, QU can be counted as one letter.
>
> 3) Bishop is not here for a reason. It is a dead end. Please tell me if it is not. Thanks!

Have fun!

---

P.S. Sorry if you guys think that Wiktionary is too broad. I will try to improve on this aspect from the next puzzle on.

Comment: Wiktionary is a somewhat questionable source for [thre](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thre) reasons: it contains words that don't actually exist in the English language.

Comment: @Bass thanks for your opinion. in my honest opinion, when you don't know a word it doesn't mean it isn't a word. that was also the moment when I learnt that thre was a word. btw, OneIsNot3 and PiIsNot3 as well :)

Comment: Is the bishop left out intentionally? :)

Comment: poor bishop :/ @jafe

Comment: @OmegaKrypton, as you may find out by checking *any* dictionary (and I'm somewhat confident about this, because I checked pretty much every single one), "thre" is, indeed, not a word.

Comment: "Thre" was used as a spelling of "three" through the 1500s, straddling the cusp between Middle and Modern English. It appears in two dictionaries that I could find: Wiktionary, as cited above, and the OED, among usage examples for the word "a" https://www.oed.com/viewdictionaryentry/Entry/1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

22 Steps using Knight -> Rook and Queen -> King from jafe's answer

> PAWN tawn tain thin thing night KNIGHT night thing thin thon toon took ROOK koro kero kern keen QUEEN keen ken kin KING

Comment: nice find! i'll accept your answer now

Answer (score 6):

25 steps

> PAWN pain pin tin thin thing night KNIGHT night thing thin thon toon took ROOK took toon ton ten teen QUEEN keen ken kin KING

Comment: i have a case with 25 ;) see if you can beat me :)

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Hmm...!

Comment: sorry I mean 26... +1 btw!

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Probably not. Knowledge of chess doesn't really help in solving this.

Comment: @jafe rot13(Vs "gnva" vf nyybjrq, naq vg vf znexrq jvgu "Ratyvfu" va Jvxgvbanel, lbh pbhyq punatr "cva gva" gb "gnva" fnivat n jbeq.)

Comment: @Bananenkopp Yeah I noticed that... from SaiBot's answer :)